# Server code error 403 when writing logs into list

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2013

i need to use this on premises working code into online

need to make some changes to work on online.the main thing is its showing the same error for all the exceptins.

````cs
        public static void writeLogsintoList(string Category_Name, string Method_Name, string Error_Message)
        {
            try
            {
                //UserCollection ouser = new UserCollection("Suyog.m@totalebizsolutions.com", "Wlcm$$2003");
                //Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientResult<PrincipalInfo>
                //request.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
                //request.Proxy.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
                ClientContext context = new ClientContext(ApplicationSiteUrl);
                List announcementsList = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Logs");
                ListItemCreationInformation itemCreateInfo = new ListItemCreationInformation();
                ListItem newItem = announcementsList.AddItem(itemCreateInfo);

                newItem["Timestamp"] = DateTime.Now;
                newItem["Category_Name"] = Category_Name;
                newItem["Method_Name"] = Method_Name;
                newItem["Error_Message"] = Error_Message;


                newItem.Update();
                context.ExecuteQuery();
                Console.WriteLine("added");
                Console.ReadLine();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
```[enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HX2Pg.png



actually its happening  for all exceptions
````

Comment: Please show the full exception with an edit to your post

Answer (score 0):

Try to download SharePointOnline.CSOM from Nuget firstly:

[image]

Then use SharePointOnlineCredentials class to pass credential, here is the code snippet for your reference:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string password = "*******";
            string account = "user@Tenant.onmicrosoft.com";
            var secret = new System.Security.SecureString();
            foreach (char c in password)
            {
                secret.AppendChar(c);
            }

            var credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(account, secret);
            using (ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext("https://Tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/sitename/"))
            {

                ctx.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(account, secret);
                ctx.Load(ctx.Web);
                ctx.ExecuteQuery();
                writeLogsintoList(ctx, "TestCategory", "TestMethod", "TestErrorMessage");


            }
        }
        public static void writeLogsintoList(ClientContext context, string Category_Name, string Method_Name, string Error_Message)
        {
            try
            {

                List announcementsList = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Logs");
                ListItemCreationInformation itemCreateInfo = new ListItemCreationInformation();
                ListItem newItem = announcementsList.AddItem(itemCreateInfo);

                newItem["Timestamp"] = DateTime.Now;
                newItem["Category_Name"] = Category_Name;
                newItem["Method_Name"] = Method_Name;
                newItem["Error_Message"] = Error_Message;


                newItem.Update();
                context.ExecuteQuery();
                Console.WriteLine("added");
                Console.ReadLine();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Have you passed the valid username and password ?

Comment: yes!the thing is the account is maintained with authentication app,is that may be reason?and one more thing when i am doing that with my personal account its working fine.

Comment: Check out the previous account permission as it's working with your personal account, should be permisssion related issue.